# (Repost) Finance annual payment amount

Tags: finance

Example 2.6 A business owner takes out a loan of 450'000 on January 1 at a fixed-interest rate of 9% per year. It is payable over 15 years level payments due on each December 31 for the first 14 years and a final payment of 50'000 due on December 31 of the 15th year. Calculate the annual payment amount.

Final answer is 56032.

How do the book come up with answer?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Can you experiment, in Excel for example, with numbers to see what fits?

Comment: What do you mean by "repost" ?

Comment: see http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You just have to set equal the future value (end of year 15) of the loan and the future value (end of year 15) of the payments.

$$\underbrace{1.09^{15}\cdot 450,000}_{\text{future value of the loan}}=r\cdot \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{1-1.09^{14}}{1-
1.09}}_{ \text{future value of the first 14 pmts}\\ \text{at the end of year 14  }}\cdot1.09}_{\text{future value of the first 14 pmts}\\ \text{at the end of year 15  }}+\underbrace{50,000}_{\text{future value of the last payment}}$$

The key point that the reference point in time on both sides of the equation is 15 years in the future.

Comment: Yes finally thanks! and I get the desired answer by solving for "r" @callculus

Comment: @Jaehaerys Your´re welcome. Nice that you´ve got the answer.